# Correct configuration to increase Umbraco Processing Memory

Tags: c#, .net, iis, umbraco, umbraco7

I keep getting a SystemOutOfMemoryException when processing large files like 1.6GB in size. I was just wondering if my configuration in web.config is correct. Below are the lines of code I modified to support large files that is more than 1GB in size

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="457286400" executionTimeout="3600" targetFramework="4.5" fcnMode="Single" />

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I'm not sure if this is correct. I also changed the IIS server to run in x64 via Tools-> Options-> Project and Solutions-> Web Projects -> "Use the 65bit version of IIS"

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I keep getting the system out of memory exception even though I already increased the memory size

UPDATE:
I'm processing a large files like .mp4 files or just anytype of file regardless of type as long as the client requires it.

Also I'm not uploading the file using a frontend. What we do is upload the large file via Filezilla and if the file is uploaded to the server we use the Umbraco MediaService to process this file to have an entry in the Media Page. We are also using Hangfire to trigger our background service to process the MediaService

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by "processing large files". is it when you are uploading them? Resizing images using image processor? Also, what kind of files?

Comment: Hi @Tim I have updated my question

Comment: Your configuration should be enough to allow big file for IIS. It is appreciated if you could post a sample code to reproduce the problem. Besides, could you find that detailed error message in windows event viewer application log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue by adding a 2nd and 3rd parameter in my Umbraco MediaService. Initially I was using `Service.MediaService.Save(iMediaFile)` but it seems that when using large file it needed to know who uploaded the file hence it needs the 2nd parameter which is the user_id and I added the third parameter to suppress any error message. As I was encountering an out of memory exception where in fact the error was I didn't pass the user_id in the second paramter. Hence my new code became `Service.MediaService.Save(iMediaFile, user_id, false)`

Again the solution was not really a configuration as my configuration was enough to process the file. The error was due to missing 2nd parameter

Answer (score 1):

Accepting large files like this, is not a best practice. Eg this gives the possibility to perform a Ddos attack.  Also you will need a lot of memory as the file will be handled in memory before persisting it to disk, hence the issue you have with memory.

The better solution would be to chunk them with javascript and send over small packets, and the stitch them back together server side.  There is a pretty good explanation on how to build this yourselves : https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/893/upload-big-files-aspnet-mvc-azure-storage
(depending on how you handle your sessions, adding it to the session might not resolve your memory issue. I guess you'll need to save it to disk)

Unrelated to the memroy exception, but make sure you wrap this in a `<location path="xxx/yyy"> your web.config stuff </location>` so that only this URL will accept large files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to solve the issue by passing a second parameter. It seems the error was misleading as my current configuration was correct and the error was not really related to running out of memory while processing my large file. It seems I just need to pass 2nd and 3rd parameter which are the user_id and the hide_error params. That solves the issue and was able to save the file correctly.